# Finding CNF of $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow p$ and $\lnot (q \wedge (\lnot p \rightarrow q)) $

Tags: logic, propositional-logic, normal-forms

I'm trying to find the CNF of the $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow p$ and $\lnot (q \wedge (\lnot p \rightarrow q))$, and afterwards proving it's validity. As i'm new to CNF i wanted to ensure i've found the right CNF before trying to move on, so for $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow p$:

the normal from is:
$p \rightarrow q \wedge q \rightarrow p$

and it's valid?

Comment: The CNF shouldn't contain the "$\rightarrow$" operation

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is incorrect as CNF. [Conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (CNF) is a normal form like

$$
  (a_1 \vee \neg a_2 \vee \dots \vee a_n) \wedge (\neg b_1 \vee \dots \vee b_m) \wedge \dots \wedge (c_1 \vee \dots \vee c_l)
$$

therefore a formula in CNF has only literals (i.e. atoms or negated atoms), $\wedge$, and $\vee$. It doesn't have $\to$.

If it's allowed to transform $p \to q$ to its equivalent formula $(\neg p) \vee q$, you can use this for the first step to convert a given formula to a CNF formula.